# Python: last item position

Tags: python, position, enumerate

So I have a huge string and I process it element by element. I want to know how much is left so I try to take the current position word minus the last position word to see how many are left. I tried something like this:

```
with codecs.open("C:\\dna_chain.txt",'r', "utf-8") as file:
    for line in file:
        temp_buffer = line.split()
        for i,word in enumerate(temp_buffer):
            print(enumerate(temp_buffer[i]))
            print(enumerate(temp_buffer[-1]))
```

I get positions in memory and they are the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`enumerate()` returns a generator object; you only printed the representation of the object, then discard it again. The second line then reused the same memory location for a now object.

You can just refer directly to the `temp_buffer` object without `enumerate()` here:

```
for i, word in enumerate(temp_buffer):
    print(temp_buffer[i])
    print(temp_buffer[-1])
```

but `temp_buffer[i]` is the same thing as `word` in that loop. `temp_buffer[-1]` is the last word in your list.

If you wanted to know how many more words there are to process, use `len(temp_buffer) - i`, the length of the `temp_buffer` list, subtracting the current position.

Comment: i tried this but it returns the word not the position

Comment: Yes, because `temp_buffer[i]` is exactly the same thing as `word`. `temp_buffer[-1]` is the last word. Are you looking for `len(temp_buffer) - i` perhaps?

Answer (score 1):

You should count the number of items beforehand:

```
words = len(temp_buffer)
```

in your code this would look like

```
import codecs

with codecs.open("C:\\dna_chain.txt",'r', "utf-8") as file:
    for line in file:
        temp_buffer = line.split()
        words = len(temp_buffer)
        for i,word in enumerate(temp_buffer):
            print(i, word, words-i-1)
```

this will print the index `i`, the word `word` and the number of remaining items in this row `words-i-1`.